# Java Android: Tesseract not blacklisting alphabets

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have developed an OCR project to recognize only digits, so I have this:

```
tessAPI.init(path, "eng");
tessApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.OEM_TESSERACT_CUBE_COMBINED);
      tessApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_WHITELIST, "0123456789");
      tessApi.setVariable(TessBaseAPI.VAR_CHAR_BLACKLIST,"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz");
```

EDITED:
In addition to the above code snippets,
I retrieved the output this way---

```
this.text = tessApi.getUTF8Text();
```

In the logcat view I have this---
The scan result modified is>>>>>>

```
/,l<‘|’ll Assovm'l‘rss
Rd. N.» 3669—87025
\‘cr1;1|N0.1 5559733‘698236653 V
I’m' 0008-0443—2248-0099
Dun-"l imc: 05/01/2015 10:41 AM
```

To binarize the bitmap I have this:

```
Pix pixValue = Binarize.otsuAdaptiveThreshold(handle);
```

//conversion is somewhat slow on the above

```
In my assets folder, I have eng.traineddata
```

But the problem is that, instead of it skipping/blacklisting the alphabets, it replaces them with a digit. Where am I wrong.

Comment: The blacklist overrides the whitelist. If you only want digits it should be ok only to define the whitelist. (see the comment in [unicharset.h](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/ccutil/unicharset.h#L376)

Comment: Still the same output.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a code snippet which demonstrates your problem. As well some information about which library and version do you use.

Comment: Okay. Will update you on that soonest. Glad if you can offer a helping thought

Comment: Have a also look there http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/. The post describes the creation of an Android OCR app. You might amend it a little bit, as it's from 2012.

Comment: I have updated my problem for a better introspection.